# How to use user defined property in construction method for a winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a textbox that only accepts numbers and a "-" for negative numbers. I would like there to be an option to disable negative numbers.

In the constructor method I want to reference the `allowNegatives` bool that is defined properties editor and do different things depending on if it allows negatives values. I'm running into the problem that the 'allowNegatives' bool is always its default value in the constructor. If I reference it elsewhere it is the correct value.

Is there an way to get the assigned property value rather than the default value in the constructor?

```
public partial class ControlIntEntry : TextBox
    {

        private bool allowNegatives = false;
        [Description("Allow negative values"), Category("Behavior")]
        public bool AllowNegatives
        {
            get { return allowNegatives; }
            set { allowNegatives = value; }
        }

        public ControlIntEntry()
        {
            // user sets AllowNegatives to true using properties editor

            InitializeComponent();
            Console.WriteLine(allowNegatives); // returns false

            if (allowNegatives)
            {
                //do one thing
            }
            else
            {
                // do something else.
            }

            Task.Run(() => AfterConstructor()); // use for testing
        }

        private async Task AfterConstructor()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(allowNegatives); //returns true
        }
}
```

Comment: Naturally a constructor has to finish running before anything else can set property values to anything else.. if you need to kick off some task based on the setting of a property value, don't do it in the constructor. How about setting your consequential actions up in the set{} ?

Comment: You should be able to apply the logic in setter of the property. Also for complex initializations which may involve multiple properties, you can implement [ISupportInitialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and put the logic inside `EndInit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can assign a value to an instance property, the class should be instantiated, so first constructor will run and then you can assign property values.

That said, to have a better understanding of what is happening here,  when you drop an instance of a control on your form at design time and set some of its properties, designer will generate a code like this:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    ...
    this.myControl1 = new MyControl();
    ...
    // 
    // myControl1
    // 
    this.myControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.myControl1.Name = "myControl1";
    this.myControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 22);
    this.myControl1.MyProperty = true;
    ...
}
```

I believe it's now clear that what is happening here. You see first the constructor of your control will run, then later property values will be set.

To use property values to configure your object can put the logic inside the setter of the property:

```
private bool myProperty = false;
public bool MyProperty
{
    get { return myProperty;}
    set 
    {
         myProperty = value;
         // some logic here.
    }
}
```

It's the most common scenario.

Another option is delaying the initializations to some time later, for example when the control handle is created by overriding `OnHandleCreated` or another suitable time.

```
// This is just an example, the event may not be a good one for your requirement
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    // some logic here
}
```

Another option for complex initialization scenarios which may involve multiple properties, you can implement [ISupportInitialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and put the logic inside `EndInit`:

```
public class MyControl : TextBox, ISupportInitialize
{
    public void BeginInit()
    {
    }

    public void EndInit()
    {
        // some logic here         
    }
}
```

Then when you drop an instance of the control on the form, this code will be generated in addition to the common code that I showed at beginning of this answer:

```
...
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.myControl1)).EndInit();
this.ResumeLayout(false);
this.PerformLayout();
...
```

(I expect it's obvious now, that) All above options will run after running the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Putting that code in the setter worked

```
public partial class ControlIntEntry : TextBox
    {

        private bool allowNegatives = false;
        [Description("Allow negative values"), Category("Behavior")]
        public bool AllowNegatives
        {
            get { return allowNegatives; }
            set 
            { 
                allowNegatives = value;
                if (allowNegatives)
                    this.KeyPress += KeyPress_AllowNegatives;
                else
                    this.KeyPress += KeyPress_PositiveOnly;
            }
        }

        public ControlIntEntry()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void KeyPress_PositiveOnly(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Char newChar = e.KeyChar;

            if (!Char.IsDigit(newChar) && newChar != 8)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }

        private void KeyPress_AllowNegatives(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Char newChar = e.KeyChar;
            int cursorIndex = this.SelectionStart;


            if (cursorIndex == 0)
            {
                if (!Char.IsDigit(newChar) && newChar != 8 && newChar != 45)
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!Char.IsDigit(newChar) && newChar != 8)
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```